# Sharepoint(2013) notification to user who created an item

Tags: notifications, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

So I want to create a list where users can add items, and after adding the item they will get an e-mail notification from only that specific item.

Is it possible to do or shall I just forget about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set Alert for this list.

[image]

[image]

Reference: [Create an alert to get notified when a file or folder changes in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-alert-to-get-notified-when-a-file-or-folder-changes-in-sharepoint-e5a79e7b-a146-46da-a9ef-d65409ba8918#Pick_tab=SharePoint)